# Sequelize : relation "<tablename>" does not exist when querying table while seeding

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, hapi.js

1. Sequelize connects with given sequelizerc / config.js file
2. Sequelize runs migration files and creates tables with defined models
3. Sequelize runs seeder files **but errors out when trying to query created data** i.e. **ERROR: relation "guest" does not exist**

**Interesting things I've noticed :** When querying the User table, I notice it doesn't return the data I expect... instead of the users on the User table it seems to be returning the actual postgres database user I set on it.

**SEEDER FILE**

```
var userId1 = uuidv4();
await queryInterface.bulkInsert(
  { tableName: 'User', schema: 'public' }, 
  [
    {email: "user1@email.com", id:userId1,  password: User.prototype.generateHash("password"), createdAt:dateUtil.createDateAsUTC(new Date()), updatedAt:dateUtil.createDateAsUTC(new Date())}
  ], {}
);

const user = await queryInterface.sequelize.query(
  `SELECT * from USER;`
);

console.log(user);

var guestId1 = uuidv4();
await queryInterface.bulkInsert(
  { tableName: 'Guest', schema: 'public' }, 
  [
    {id:guestId1, userId: userId1, createdAt:dateUtil.createDateAsUTC(new Date()), updatedAt:dateUtil.createDateAsUTC(new Date())}
  ], {}
);

const guest = await queryInterface.sequelize.query(
  `SELECT * from Guest;`
);
```

From digging around it seems that possibly its not using the right db schema?  I have one in postgres under `public`, all the tables are created correctly, and seeded data is added to the db correctly.  I have tried to add the schema to the config.js and on the model files, but nothing works.

**CONFIG.JS**

```
development: {
        username: process.env.DATABASE_USERNAME,
        password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
        database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
        host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
        url: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
        dialect: 'postgres',
        define: {
            schema: "public"
        }
    }
```

**Guest.js**

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  var Guest = sequelize.define('Guest', {}, 
  {
    tableName:"Guest",
  });
  Guest.associate = function(models) {
    Guest.belongsTo(models.User, {as: 'User', foreignKey: 'userId'}); // Adds userId 
  };
  return Guest;
};
```

When logging out queryInterface models seems to be empty....

```
QueryInterface {
  sequelize:
   Sequelize {
     options:
      { dialect: 'postgres',
        dialectModulePath: null,
        host: 'localhost',
        protocol: 'postgres',
        define: {},
        query: {},
        sync: {},
        timezone: '+00:00',
        logging: [Function: logMigrator],
        omitNull: false,
        native: false,
        replication: false,
        ssl: false,
        pool: {},
        quoteIdentifiers: true,
        hooks: {},
        retry: [Object],
        transactionType: 'DEFERRED',
        isolationLevel: null,
        databaseVersion: '9.4.0',
        typeValidation: false,
        benchmark: false,
        operatorsAliases: true,
        username: 'username',
        password: 'password',
        database: 'dbname',
        url: 'postgres://username:password@localhost:5432/dbname',
        port: '5432' },
     config:
      { database: '<dbname>',
        username: '<username>',
        password: 'password',
        host: 'localhost',
        port: '5432',
        pool: {},
        protocol: 'postgres',
        native: false,
        ssl: false,
        replication: false,
        dialectModulePath: null,
        keepDefaultTimezone: undefined,
        dialectOptions: undefined },
     dialect:
      PostgresDialect {
        sequelize: [Circular],
        connectionManager: [Object],
        QueryGenerator: [Object] },
     queryInterface: [Circular],
     models: {},
     modelManager: ModelManager { models: [], sequelize: [Circular] }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Corrected the issue with **double quotes** around tablename:

const guest = await queryInterface.sequelize.query(
  `SELECT * from "Guest";`
);